# How to write an SQL query that searches for a group of words from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a query for Stack Exchange's very own [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). This query will create a temporary table containing a list of commonly misspelled words and their proper spellings and then search through the posts to find them.

Here is what I have so far (minus the comments):

```
DECLARE @SpellingMistakes TABLE (wrong VARCHAR(255), right VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @SpellingMistakes (wrong, right)
VALUES ('ubunut', 'ubuntu')

SELECT Id as [Post Link]
FROM Posts
WHERE
    ...
```

And that's where I get stuck - in the `WHERE` clause. I need some way of saying "if `Posts.Body` contains any of `@SpellingMistakes.wrong`". However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Note: the data explorer uses Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: A lousy way would be `Posts.Body like + '%' +( select SpellingMistakes.wrong from SpellingMistakes) + '%'` - something of this sort - not sure if it's the right syntax

Comment: Sadly `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'Posts' because it is not full-text indexed.`

Comment: I thought the data explorer use Azure, not as fully featured as 2008 R2.  SO's backend is SQL Server...

Comment: @OMGPonies they've moved away from Azure http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know MS SQL, but most SQL implementations have a 'LIKE' equivalent. So in that case, you could join the two tables and use LIKE in the JOIN condition.

```
SELECT Id as link
FROM Posts P JOIN SpellingMistakes S
ON P.Body LIKE '%'+S.wrong+'%'
```

EDIT: Assuming `Posts` is a large table (and `SpellingMistakes` is not too small either), this will take a lot of resources. One way to tackle this is to split table `Posts` into smaller subsets and construct multiple statements.

```
SELECT Id as link
FROM (SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id<=10000) P 
JOIN 
SpellingMistakes S
ON P.Body LIKE '%'+S.wrong+'%'

SELECT Id as link
FROM (SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id<=20000 and Id>10000) P 
JOIN    
SpellingMistakes S
ON P.Body LIKE '%'+S.wrong+'%'
```

And so on.

Comment: I did something similar to that and the server choked claiming (in an error message) that it "ran out of resources." Can I be certain that this query won't use a ridiculous amount of resources?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Joining 2 large tables will always take a lot of resources [`O(nm)`]. I can't think of any other solution right now. The way I usually do large table joins is to break down the join into multiple statements, each using a smaller subset of the bigger table. So, in this case, if you can specify a condition on table `Posts` to extract only a subset, then the `JOIN` should be able to work with less resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id as PostLink
FROM Posts p
WHERE   
EXISTS 
     (
      SELECT * 
      FROM @SpellingMistakes 
      WHERE p.Body LIKE '%' + wrong + '%' 
      )
```